# Application crashes and I cant figure out why

Tags: applications, 9.0-pie, crashes, chromebook

I am trying to run an android application on a chromebook (android 9), but every time I try to open it, it has a black screen, then crashes. I have tried the basic things, clearing cache, re-installing the application, resetting my device. I tried to use logcat to trace the crash (By running the `adb logcat` command)

Here is the logcat

```
03-05 13:39:31.836   863  1503 I ArcIntentHelperService: Handling org.chromium.arc.intent_helper.SET_IN_TOUCH_MODE from Chrome...
03-05 13:39:31.858   597  1034 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity:899 android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity:401 org.chromium.arc.applauncher.AppLauncherService.launchIntent:1869 org.chromium.arc.applauncher.AppLauncherService.launchAppWithWindowInfo:1826 org.chromium.arc.mojom.AppInstance_Internal$Stub.accept:1009 
03-05 13:39:31.860   119   403 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global/.GlobalUnsafeMainActivity} from uid 1000
03-05 13:39:31.860   119   403 W ActivityManager: getValidLaunchStackOnDisplay: can't launch on displayId 0
03-05 13:39:31.868   119   403 I ActivityManagerInjector: getResolvedRootLaunchBounds called with root activity {N-unresizeable 0x0, AC, PropertyRecord{mVersion=3, mDisplayId=0, mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), mRestoreBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), mWindowMode=1, mWasUserResized=false, mImmersive=false, mLastWindowStateInClamShell=-1, mWindowLayoutAffinity=10060:null}}
03-05 13:39:31.868   119   403 E WindowManagerInjectorArc: setArcAttributeWindowSizeConstraints: cannot find task: 19
03-05 13:39:31.868   119   403 I ActivityManagerInjectorArc: updateCaptionLocked: skipping activity that isn't fully started
03-05 13:39:31.872   119   403 I ActivityManagerInjectorArc: notifyActivityAddedToTask: added to new task. activity=ActivityRecord{df7a9b3 u0 com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global/.GlobalUnsafeMainActivity t19}
03-05 13:39:31.872    11    60 D wayland-service: Couldn't find a window for task_id 19, will set orientation lock when next added.
03-05 13:39:31.875   119   334 D DecorView[global]: Cannot get the activity to get CaptionConfiguration.
03-05 13:39:31.891   597  1034 I ArcAppLauncherService: Activity launched for Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global/.GlobalUnsafeMainActivity }.
03-05 13:39:31.896   119   334 D ArcInputCompatHandler: Using touchscreen emulation for all games.
03-05 13:39:31.948    11    11 D wayland-service: Creating app window for task_id 19 from package 'com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global'
03-05 13:39:31.949    11    11 I wayland-service: Set task 19 orientation lock from package 'com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global'
03-05 13:39:31.949    11    11 D wayland-service: Setting orientation lock to 3 for task_id 19.
03-05 13:39:31.949    11    11 I wayland-service: Set task 19 window type 1from package 'com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global
03-05 13:39:31.949    11    11 D wayland-service: ApplyBackgroundColor for task_id 19, color=-16777216
03-05 13:39:31.874   119   403 I ActivityManagerInjectorArc: notifyActivityAddedToTask: added to new task. activity=ActivityRecord{df7a9b3 u0 com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global/.GlobalUnsafeMainActivity t19}
03-05 13:39:31.958   119   403 D ActivityManagerInjectorArc: taskOcclusionChanged: taskId=19 does not support PIP
03-05 13:39:31.961   119   358 I InputDispatcher: Dropping event because there is no touchable window at (896, 479).
03-05 13:39:32.372   119   288 I OrientationSynchronizer: Setting rotation is timed out
03-05 13:39:32.373   119  2139 E ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked: Unknown animationType=0
03-05 13:39:32.397   119   290 I ActivityManager: Start proc 5722:com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global/u0a60 for activity com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global/.GlobalUnsafeMainActivity
03-05 13:39:32.441  5722  5722 D houdini : [7508] Initialize library(version: 9.0.5c_z.51331 RELEASE)... successfully.
03-05 13:39:32.446  5722  5722 E allstars.globa: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
03-05 13:39:32.503    11   642 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to set client state on removed layer: org.chromium.arc.home/org.chromium.arc.home.HomeActivity#0
03-05 13:39:32.503    11   642 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: org.chromium.arc.home/org.chromium.arc.home.HomeActivity#0
03-05 13:39:32.507    11   642 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to set client state on removed layer: org.chromium.arc.home/org.chromium.arc.home.HomeActivity#0
03-05 13:39:32.507    11   642 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: org.chromium.arc.home/org.chromium.arc.home.HomeActivity#0
03-05 13:39:32.560  5722  5722 W allstars.globa: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
03-05 13:39:32.561  5722  5722 I chatty  : uid=10060(com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global) identical 22 lines
03-05 13:39:32.561  5722  5722 W allstars.globa: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
03-05 13:39:32.669  5722  5722 I FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
03-05 13:39:32.678   119  2041 D vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.cros.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
03-05 13:39:32.705   119  2041 I ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
03-05 13:39:32.705   119  2041 I ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
03-05 13:39:32.722   119  2041 E libEGL  : eglSetBlobCacheFuncsANDROID resulted in an error: 0x300c
03-05 13:39:32.722   119  2041 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-05 13:39:32.722   119  2041 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
03-05 13:39:32.731   119  2041 E OpenGLRenderer: Device claims wide gamut support, cannot find matching config, error = EGL_SUCCESS
03-05 13:39:33.044   597   597 D ArcAppTaskTracker: Calculating task stack diff.
03-05 13:39:33.046   597   597 D ArcAppTaskTracker: Task created: 19 - ComponentInfo{com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global/com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global.GlobalUnsafeMainActivity} .
03-05 13:39:33.084   597   597 D ArcAppTaskTracker: Active task: 19.
03-05 13:39:33.326   119   145 I system_server: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 59995(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 41(1780KB) LOS objects, 42% free, 9MB/16MB, paused 9.666ms total 596.473ms
03-05 13:39:33.339   119   141 W System  : A resource failed to call release. 
03-05 13:39:33.353   119   141 W System  : A resource failed to call release. 
03-05 13:39:33.433  5722  5741 I FA      : App measurement is starting up, version: 16250
03-05 13:39:33.433  5722  5741 I FA      : To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
03-05 13:39:33.433  5722  5741 I FA      : To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
03-05 13:39:33.433  5722  5741 I FA      :   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global
03-05 13:39:33.491  5722  5722 D OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
03-05 13:39:33.561  5722  5722 D JackpotPlatformMessage: ActivityCallback.onCreate(Bundle)
03-05 13:39:33.586  5722  5722 D ArcInputCompatHandler: Using touchscreen emulation for all games.
03-05 13:39:33.586  5722  5722 D ArcInputCompatHandler: Using touchscreen emulation for unity apps.
03-05 13:39:33.612  5722  5732 I allstars.globa: Background concurrent copying GC freed 9369(1199KB) AllocSpace objects, 8(224KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 1757KB/3MB, paused 5.478ms total 81.917ms
03-05 13:39:33.641  5722  5722 D vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
03-05 13:39:33.641  5722  5722 D vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.cros.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
03-05 13:39:33.709   119   297 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global/.GlobalUnsafeMainActivity: +1s291ms
03-05 13:39:33.710   119   287 W system_server: Failed to determine oat file name for dex location /data/app/com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global-gx42EdHfqpRKf5asfmQ7aw==/base.apk: Dalvik cache directory does not exist
03-05 13:39:33.715   119   403 D ActivityManagerInjectorArc: taskOcclusionChanged: taskId=19 does not support PIP
03-05 13:39:33.900    11    47 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to set client state on removed layer: Splash Screen com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global#0
03-05 13:39:33.900    11    47 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: Splash Screen com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global#0
03-05 13:39:34.072  5722  5747 I Unity   : SystemInfo CPU = ARM64 FP ASIMD AES VMH, Cores = 2, Memory = 3806mb
03-05 13:39:34.072  5722  5747 I Unity   : SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 2 big (mask: 0x3), 0 little (mask: 0x0)
03-05 13:39:34.076  5722  5747 I Unity   : ApplicationInfo com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global version 1.0.1 build 242cadff-95df-41d3-9bc5-9ab51555b9b0
03-05 13:39:34.076  5722  5747 I Unity   : Built from '2018.4/staging' branch, Version '2018.4.2f1 (d6fb3630ea75)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
03-05 13:39:34.167  5722  5741 I FA      : Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
03-05 13:39:37.838   119   358 W InputDispatcher: channel 'a1a6cc com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global/com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global.GlobalUnsafeMainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
03-05 13:39:37.838   119   358 E InputDispatcher: channel 'a1a6cc com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global/com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global.GlobalUnsafeMainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-05 13:39:37.839    43    43 I Zygote  : Process 5722 exited cleanly (0)
03-05 13:39:37.840   119   403 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{a1a6cc u0 com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global/com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global.GlobalUnsafeMainActivity}
03-05 13:39:37.840   119   403 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'a1a6cc com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global/com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global.GlobalUnsafeMainActivity (server)'`
```

This is where the application dies

```
`03-05 13:39:37.840   119   532 I ActivityManager: Process com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global (pid 5722) has died: fore TOP 
03-05 13:39:37.842   119   532 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{df7a9b3 u0 com.klab.lovelive.allstars.global/.GlobalUnsafeMainActivity t19}: app died, no saved state
03-05 13:39:37.843   119   291 W libprocessgroup: kill(-5722, 9) failed: No such process
03-05 13:39:37.843   119   291 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10060 pid 5722 in 2ms
03-05 13:39:37.846   119   532 E ActivityManagerInjectorArc: taskDragFinished: taskId=19 has invalid operation
03-05 13:39:37.856   119   297 W ActivityManager: setHasOverlayUi called on unknown pid: 5722
03-05 13:39:37.903   119   358 I InputDispatcher: Dropping event because there is no touchable window at (896, 479).
03-05 13:39:37.966   119   365 E ArcGfxMetrics: Failed to find pattern in output: Janky frames: (\d+) \(.+\%\).
03-05 13:39:37.968   885   898 D ArcMediaControllerManager: onTaskMovedToFront: 2
03-05 13:39:38.058   597   597 D ArcAppTaskTracker: Calculating task stack diff.
03-05 13:39:38.058   597   597 D ArcAppTaskTracker: Task destroyed: 19 .
03-05 13:39:38.059   597   597 D ArcAppTaskTracker: Active task: 2.
03-05 13:39:38.078   885   898 I ArcMediaControllerManager: onAppBecameActive: org.chromium.arc.applauncher
03-05 13:39:38.195   597   597 D ArcAppTaskTracker: Calculating task stack diff.
03-05 13:39:38.196   597   597 D ArcAppTaskTracker: Active task: 2.
```

Is there a way to view a more detailed log about the application because the log doesnt seem to say WHY the application died, it just says that the application died.

Comment: Does the app work on a regular Android device and an emulator?

Comment: @Robert , yes, the application works in emulators like bluestacks and on regular android devices.

Comment: I rooted the android partition on my chromebook (Didnt install supersu tho) and now older versions of the application will launch (The newest version doesnt support root) What should I do next?